# MotionLayout/Carousel current state

Tags: android, carousel, android-motionlayout

I have `MotionLayout` with `Carousel`. I want to run some code, when user swipe and move to next slide.

To simplity - I have three slides, SLIDE 1, SLIDE 2, SLIDE3. I need to run some code (change other UI elements, make a toast, ...) when current item is changed. Is this possible?

I tried following:

```
((MotionLayout)v).setTransitionListener(new MotionLayout.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStarted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionChange(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1, float v) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCompleted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionTrigger(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, boolean b, float v) {}
    });
```

But in onTransitionCompleted, I can find current transition only (if user swiped forward or backward, not the current item).

Complete code is not necessary, I used first example of the [official experiments repo](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/tree/main/projects/CarouselExperiments). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your `Carousel.Adapter` should receive `onNewItem(int index)` call when item is changed, is that not the case?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

OnTransitionCompleted has the current state/constraintSet passed as an argument.
Not sure what you are asking

`void onTransitionCompleted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int currentId);`

Comment: `currentId` returns id of `Transition`, not the actual view. When I move from 1st to 2nd, `currentId` is the same as when I move from 2nd to 3rd.